# Unable to access running jupyter session over SSH

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook on remote remote machine `user@remote`  and use it from my local machine.  I did

```
local@host  $ ssh user@remote
user@remote $ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
http://localhost:8889/?token=2656c58d730bd3779be5f1b6af9356b4de7113c927c9c722
```

Which starts the jupyter session in remote machine. Then, on my local machine then I do

```
local@host  $ ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 user@remote
```

when I open this(`http://localhost:8888/?token=2656c58d730bd3779be5f1b6af9356b4de7113c927c9c722`
), it says

```
local@host  $ channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: On your remote machine, when you start the notebook,  an URL containing a long token is displayed. You must copy-paste that URL in your browser address bar and simply replace localhost:8889 by localhost:8888. The token serves for authentication here.

Comment: I tried that (with the token) too. (The problem still persists. Question updated accordingly).

Comment: Not sure, but I always use ssh -N -f -L ...

Comment: Didn't work with the `-f` switch too.

Comment: This is strange indeed. I am unable to reproduce the issue with the commands you provided.